# Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "book-detail"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Previously I was using `ModelSerializer` and there were no  error. When I replaced it with `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` this error was thrown

```
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "book
detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API,
or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

this is `serializers.py` file:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['id', 'url', 'title', 'subtitle', 'isbn']
```

`model.py`

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=13)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`views.py`

```
class BookListView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

and `urls.py`

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('books', BookListView)


app_name = "books"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

view name `book-detail` doesn't exist in my views, probably Django created it automatically and I don't know where to find and debug it? Thank you.

here is the traceback of error -

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/books/

Django Version: 3.1.2
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'books.apps.BooksConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py", line 398, in to_representation
    url = self.get_url(value, self.view_name, request, format)
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py", line 336, in get_url
    return self.reverse(view_name, kwargs=kwargs, request=request, format=format)
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\reverse.py", line 47, in reverse
    url = _reverse(viewname, args, kwargs, request, format, **extra)
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\reverse.py", line 60, in _reverse
    url = django_reverse(viewname, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, **extra)
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

During handling of the above exception (Reverse for 'book-detail' not found. 'book-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.), another exception occurred:
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 46, in list
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 745, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 663, in to_representation
    return [
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 664, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "D:\All\Back-end Django\REST API Django\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py", line 413, in to_representation
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg % self.view_name)

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /books/
Exception Value: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "book-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

Comment: The code is working on my end and I am able to create a new book via the api:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/books/

Have you modified the model and forgot to rerun migrations? Restart your server and try again? If it still doesn't work, can you provide the error message?

Comment: Yes, I rerun the migrations. restarted the server and I am still getting the error. I just added the traceback.

Comment: Still no error on my end and everything is working properly. I would test this by modifying the "app_name = "books"" to something else as they may overlap with the router URL or try creating another model with the same fields, serializer, view and check if it works

Comment: I even created a new project and I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once faced this problem too but I fixed by doing this:

**urls.py (project)**
you might need to provide namespace for your app in root `urls.py`

```py
path('your_url', include(('your_app.urls', 'your_app'), namespace="your_app"))
```

**serializers.py**
add a `HyperlinkedIdentityField`

```py
class BookSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    # add this 
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="your_app:book-detail")

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['id', 'url', 'title', 'subtitle', 'isbn']
```

**urls.py** (app)
add `basename`

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
# add basename
router.register('books', BookListView, basename="books")
```

Docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/